# SELinux - Script uploaded SSH keys to remote server but cannot connect via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, selinux, rsa

I wrote this script which now works perfectly on systems without SElinux installed.

```
echo Enter server IP:
read server
scp /home/Zenoss/.ssh/authorized_keys random@$server:/home/random
sshpass -p randompassword  ssh -t  random@$server sudo -i 'useradd zenoss; sudo mkdir /home/zenoss/.ssh; sudo mv /home/random/authorized_keys /home/zenoss/.ssh/;
sudo chmod 700 /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo chmod 600 /home/zenoss/.ssh/authorized_keys;
sudo chown -R zenoss /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo chgrp -R zenoss /home/zenoss/.ssh;
exit'
```

So on servers without SElinux the script works and then Zenoss can log in to the remote server via SSH and start to monitor. However on systems with SELinux enabled, the script works, but Zenoss cannot SSH onto the remote server, the debug information shows that its not seeing the authorized_keys file that was successfully set up.

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ***** port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ***************
The authenticity of host '******' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is **************************
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '*******' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zenoss/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
zenoss@****s password:
```

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can work around it, disabling SELinux isnt an option.

KR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the context of `.ssh` and `.ssh/authorized_keys` file is wrong. Do a `sudo restorecon -R -v /home/zenoss/.ssh` and try again.

Comment: Thanks this worked fine, this command only re-lables the security settings applicable to .ssh doesnt it? I dont want to lessen any security settings overall.

Comment: It restores the correct selinux context for the .ssh folder.